# Clarification on process involving the central limit theorem

Tags: probability

From Example 9.3 in Grinstead and Snell's Introduction to Probability:

Dartmouth College would like to have 1050 freshmen. This college cannot accomodate more than 1060. Assume that each applicant accepts with probability $0.6$ and that the acceptances can be modeled by Bernoulli trials. If the college accepts 1700, what is the probability that it will have too many acceptances?

Its mathematical explanation is the following:

\begin{align*}
P(S_{1700}>1060) &= P(S_{1700}\geq1061)\\
&=P(S_{1700}^*\geq\frac{1060.5-1020}{20})\\
&=P(S_{1700}^*\geq2.025)
\end{align*}

My question is why does the book choose 1060.5 for $S^*$? Is it an arbitrary decimal between 1060 and 1061? It comes out of nowhere and doesn't really clarify what $S^*$ is meant to be besides $$S_n^*=\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{npq}}.$$

Comment: See [Continuity Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. 1061-1/2 becomes 1060.5 because we approximating this discrete distribution and the continuous normal distribution. Feel free to post the answer so I can throw some rep your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_{1700}^*$ is the normal random variable being used to approximate the binomial random variable $S_{1700}$

I would take the normal approximation to have the same mean of $1700\times 0.6=1020$ and variance of $1700\times 0.6\times 0.4 =408$ as the binomial distribution, though note that the standard deviation is in fact closer to $20.2$ than to $20$ and this has as large impact as the point you have spotted.  They have taken a standardised version instead to have mean $0$ and variance $1$, which makes no real difference except to alter location and scale

The problems come because the binomial random variable $S_{1700}$ can only take integer values, so the question is either $P(S_{1700}>1060)$ or $P(S_{1700}\geq1061)$ and both of these give the same answer of about $0.0222$

But $P\left(S_{1700}^*>\frac{1060-1020}{20.2}\right)$ and $P\left(S_{1700}^*\geq \frac{1061-1020}{20.2}\right)$ are different for a normal distribution as it is a continuous distribution over the real numbers, and there is no obvious reason to choose one over the other.  You can instead take an intermediate value and find $P\left(S_{1700}^*>\frac{1060.5-1020}{20.2}\right)$ or $P\left(S_{1700}^*\geq\frac{1060.5-1020}{20.2}\right)$ which are the same, and this is called a continuity correction.  To see the impact:

- $P\left(S_{1700}^*>\dfrac{1060-1020}{20.2}\right) \approx 0.0238$
- $P\left(S_{1700}^*\geq\dfrac{1061-1020}{20.2}\right) \approx 0.0212$
- $P\left(S_{1700}^*>\dfrac{1060.5-1020}{20.2}\right)=P\left(S_{1700}^*\geq\dfrac{1060.5-1020}{20.2}\right) \approx 0.225$